# Symfony2 session cannot get or clear namespace

Tags: symfony, session, namespaces

I am using symfony 2 session namespace and I'm able to set vars correctly. However, when clearing the namespace so as to clear all session vars in it, it does not work as well as getting the list of vars in the namespace.

I already have this in config.yml

```
parameters:
    session.attribute_bag.class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag
```

And in my controller

```
$session = $this->get('session');

// works
$session->set('mynamespace/var1', 'some value');
$session->get('mynamespace/var1');
$session->remove('mynamespace/var1');

// does not work
$session->get('mynamespace');  // returns NULL
$session->remove('mynamespace');  // does not remove the namespace vars
```

Can anyone help me why getting or clearning symfony 2 session namespaces is not working?

Comment: Seem your conf is not loaded correclty, try to verify which parameter the container is use with the command `php app/console container:debug --parameter=session.attribute_bag.class`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and here's the result: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag

Comment: I have encountered this again today on the latest symfony version and have not found yet an answer.